# Android app works in debug but not in release, idk why

Tags: android, firebase, twitter

The login with Twitter works ins debug, but not in release, also the size of the apk is bigger in the debug.
Where is the problem??

i have 3 activitys

this is the build.grandle

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 29
    buildToolsVersion "29.0.2"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.PolDevs.MyClickerGame"
        minSdkVersion 23
        targetSdkVersion 29
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:19.1.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:19.1.0'
    implementation 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-auth:4.1.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:17.2.2'
    implementation 'com.twitter.sdk.android:twitter-core:3.1.0'

    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.0'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.1.1'
}

apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Comment: do u have api key for both debug and release?

Answer (score 0):

Open the documentation for all the libraries you are using and double check if they have any specific rules to be put in `proguard` since that is enabled during release build. `proguard` obfuscates you’re APK when making a release build, which means removing code like annotations and comments etc. which also reduces the size of the apk. 
So for some libraries to work, you have to specify some rules in your `proguard` file to no obfuscate certain things. Common error to be careful of when maiking debug and release builds.

Comment: Where is the proguard

Comment: Search for a file named `proguard-rules.pro` (app level) where you would specify the rules. Here is the documentation you would want to refer to: https://developer.android.com/studio/build/shrink-code Also have a look here for twitter: https://github.com/twitterdev/TwitterKitSample/blob/master/Android/DisplayTweets/proguard-com.twitter.sdk.android.twitter.txt